# Failed to pull image "gcr.io/blah/blah":

Tags: kubernetes

We started getting an error when trying to update the image tag of a deployment and its pod

> Failed to pull image "gcr.io/blah/blah": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error: Status 429 trying to pull repository gcr.io/blah/blah: "Quota Exceeded." Error syncing pod

Randomly it started yesterday in Google Container Builder twice (the same error anyway) and stopped. Then it started during our deployment to two different pods any ideas on how to debug? Its currently stopping all deployments

Thanks
Mark

Answer (score 0):

according to the error message it's seems like one of your quota has exceeded...

select your project inside `Google Cloud Platform` and on the menu go to
IAM & admin -> Quotas

on the right you will see `Used` column and pick the service that has exceeded, 
then press `EDIT QUOTAS` on the top and increase your demand.